# How do I press F9 in byobu over SSH?

Tags: ssh, byobu

According to the man page for `byobu`, entering <kbd>F9</kbd> while in `byobu` should bring up the "Configuration Menu."  However, I'm using SSH to connect to the Linux box, so I need to enter the escape sequence for <kbd>F9</kbd>, rather than pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key itself.

As I described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211923/escape-sequences-for-function-keys-f1-f12-especially-f11-and-f12), I used the suggested method [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53589/9605) to determine the escape sequences for <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> on my platform (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS).  As I described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211923/escape-sequences-for-function-keys-f1-f12-especially-f11-and-f12), I found (among other things) that the escape sequence for <kbd>F9</kbd> is `^[Ow`.

My question is, how do I enter `^[Ow` in the terminal?

I start `byobu` by entering:

```
byobu
```

Then I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which enters `^[`.  Then I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (capital "O"), followed by <kbd>W</kbd> (lowercase "w").

In other words, my keystrokes inside `byobu` are these:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

<kbd>Esc</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

<kbd>W</kbd>

I obtain `^[Ow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  However, I get this error:

```
w: command not found
```

Evidently, I am entering the escape sequence incorrectly.  What keystrokes must I use to enter it correctly?

(Note: I am using [SSH Secure Shell (now called Tectia SSH Client)](http://www.ssh.com/products/tectia-ssh), not PuTTY, to connect to the Linux box via SSH.)

Answer (score 0):

The apparent problem is that you are typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> before the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Control/V is usually the `lnext` (*literal-next*) character, which tells the [terminal driver](http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~gboyd/cs260a/online/terminals/stty.html) to not do anything special for the following character.  That lets it pass through to the application (or shell) which ignores it, and likewise the Capital/O likewise is ignored (or legal in some sense).  The application finally notices a problem on Lower/w, for whatever reason.

By the way, the method used for determining the key sequences is relying on a particular setting of the `TERM` environment variable, which the application uses to look-up in the terminal database.  (It probably is [`vt100`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-vt100)).  You could in principle set it to another value (one whose terminfo entry has 12 function keys) and send the corresponding escape sequences using the same method.